# BAckward propagation neural networks weight updation remains constant for every iteration

Tags: python

I am trying back propagation in neural networks with input features are 401 for a sample set of 5000. It has One hidden unit with a size of 25 and output layer of size 10. I initialize my weights and when I am running the backpropagation to update my weights, weights remains constant for second iteration onwards. Can somebody please help me to sort it out?

Comment: Is this some code for us to look at? What is the error? What is the expected behavior? Please read this document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, Daniel for the confusion. I am trying to implement backpropagation algorithm. My sample set size was 5000 with no of features are 401. It contains one hidden layer of size 25 and an output of size 10 labels. When I am trying to run 101 epochs and update theta values with the corresponding delta from every epoch/iteration and calculating the cost function. When I am doing that for the first iteration my cost function was 7.09 and from second iteration it reaming constant as 109.09. Can you please suggest me how to use the updated delta as theta values.

Comment: Add the code you developed for your first iteration and second iteration, we need to see the code, keep in mind this is for programming questions, so we need to see the code you wrote.